# How to replicate this text from an image in CSS?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have text in an image that I'm trying to replicate in HTML with CSS. However I feel like there might be a better approach to mine (setting each line its own font size).

This is the image I'm trying to replicate:
[image: Text in an image]

The issues with the current solution:

- Doesn't scale great on different screen sizes
- Some lines are longer than others (aren't justified?)

Any suggestions on doing this properly?

```css
.big-text {
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-justify: inter-character;
  font-size: 5rem;
  line-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

<div class="col-md-4 big-text">
  <span>FIREWORK</span>
  <span style="font-size: 7rem;">&amp; PYRO</span>
  <span style="color: #fd0227; font-size: 8rem;">FIRING</span>
  <span style="font-size: 5.6rem;">SYSTEMS</span>
</div>
```

Comment: do u use bootstrap?

Comment: @לבנימלכה Yes, just added the tag, my bad.

Comment: if you put a break tag it will resemble, but for scaling you need use media query or a best solution is SVG

Comment: @DickensAS Fair enough, I'm also starting to think that SVG might be the best and easiest way forward...

Comment: I made you a proper [mcve] using the `[<>]` snippet editor

Answer (score 2):

Try this SVG

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 80" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <text y="20" font-size="0.95em">FIREWORK</text>
  <text y="40" font-size="1.45em">&PYRO</text>
  <text y="60" fill="red" font-size="1.5em">FIRING</text>
  <text y="75" font-size="1.1em">SYSTEMS</text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following example, this is for one display, preferably web. If you want to scale, you could do that with media queries to target mobile and web

```
<div class="image-text">
 <p>Firework</p>
 <p class="text-red">& PYRO</p>
 <p>Firing</p>
 <p>Systems</p>
</div>

.image-text p{
   padding:0;
   margin:0;
   font-size:28px;
   font-weight:bold;
   letter-spacing:1.2px
  }

.image-text p:nth-of-type(3){
  font-size:42px
 }

.image-text p:nth-of-type(4){
  font-size:32px
 }

.text-red{
  color:red
 }
```

Checkout in CodePen [Link Here](https://codepen.io/delalluyah/pen/mdPKbpv)

Answer (score 1):

Some problems don't have pretty solutions, and I think this is one of them. At the end of the day each line needs its own font size set manually. Whether you do this inline or with CSS, the resulting code just doesn't look great.

However, if you prevent line wrapping then it does scale quite nicely thanks to the `rem` units. Try it yourself by adjusting `font-size` in `:root`

```css
:root {
  font-size: 15px;
}

.big-text {
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-justify: inter-word;
  font-size: 5rem;
  line-height: 100%;
}

.big-text span {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-md-4 big-text">
  <span>FIREWORK</span>
  <span style="font-size: 7rem;">&amp; PYRO</span>
  <span style="color: #fd0227; font-size: 8rem;">FIRING</span>
  <span style="font-size: 5.6rem;">SYSTEMS</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To pile your `span`s you can set them in `display:block`.

Aside , you mays used a smaller `line-height` and `margin` instead to keep an equal gap in between lines of span.
Also `font-size` calculated from a `px` and `vw` value can help .

demo screenshot & below of the idea:

[image]

```css
.big-text {
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-justify: inter-character;
  font-size:calc(12px + 2.45vw);
  line-height: 0.7;
  background:gray;/*see me for debug*/

}

.big-text>span {
  display: block;
  width:max-content;
  margin:8px auto ;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 big-text">
      <span>FIREWORK</span>
      <span style="font-size:1.45em">&amp; PYRO</span>
      <span style="color: #fd0227; font-size: 1.65em">FIRING</span>
      <span style="font-size:1.17em;">SYSTEMS</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

mediaquerie can also be used to resize your text, but also modify the layout , here is an example (for the fun)  with mediaquerie setting the first span sideways on bigger screen.demo : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/abNKbyP or snippet below.

[image]

```css
.big-text {
  font-family: "Roboto Condensed", sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-justify: inter-character;
  font-size: calc(12px + 2.45vw);
  line-height: 0.7;
  background: gray;
  /*see me for debug*/
}

.big-text>span {
  display: block;
  width: max-content;
  margin: 8px auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 769px) {
  .vertical-md {
    writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    transform: scale(-1);
    font-size: 0.615em;
    color:#fd0227;
    -webkit-text-stroke:1px #fff
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 big-text">
      <span class="float-md-left vertical-md">FIREWORK</span>
      <span style="font-size:1.45em">&amp; PYRO</span>
      <span style="color: #fd0227; font-size: 1.65em">FIRING</span>
      <span style="font-size:1.17em;">SYSTEMS</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be done with svg.

The [textLenght](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/textLength) attribute will make your text justified if you set it to 100%. Note that the space between the letters change accordingly.

The [x](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/x) and [y](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/y) attributes will set the exact position you want your text to  be displayed.

The [viewBox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox) attribute defines the position and dimension, in user space, of an SVG viewport.

[The source for this answer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/text)

```css
html,body,svg { height:100% }
```

```html
<!-- Learn about this code on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/text -->

<svg viewBox="0 0 140 150" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <style>
    .small { font: italic 13px sans-serif; }
    .heavy { font: bold 30px sans-serif; }

    /* Note that the color of the text is set with the    *
     * fill property, the color property is for HTML only */
    .system { font: italic 40px serif; fill: red; }
  </style>

  <text textLength="100%" x="0" y="10" class="small">Firework</text>
  <text textLength="100%"  x="0" y="32" class="heavy">& PYRO</text>
  <text textLength="100%"  x="0" y="43" class="small">FIRING</text>
  <text textLength="100%"  x="0" y="72" class="system">SYSTEM</text>
  
</svg>
```